# Recieving Javascript Variable from View to controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

My View contain this code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
data:  "val"= + val,
dataType: 'script',
ype: 'post',
url: "/portfolio/update"
 );
```

In my controller I have this code:

```
j=params[:"val"]
h=j.split(" ")
```

Now I am getting this in my rails console:
Parameters = {"val"=>"            Default                  id3                  id4                  id5              test1              test2              fro  "}
and j is a nil class. 
Any guesses why i am not receiving value in controller. I just started with fronted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending your data as an object as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  data: { val: $.toJSON(val) },
  dataType: 'script',
  type: 'post',
  url: "/portfolio/update"
);
```

Then in your controller, access `val` parameter as follows:

```
j=params[:val]
```

Comment: can You tell me how to call this function on button press in view?

Comment: @DeependerSingla, I'm sure you've already solved the "call this function on button press", if not you need to place this ajax call in the click handler of `click` event.  Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/click/.  Also please add a comment here or post a new question if you run into any problems.